# agent-based simulation: performance issue: Python vs NetLogo & Repast

Tags: python, performance, simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm replicating a small piece of Sugarscape agent simulation model in Python 3. I found the performance of my code is ~3 times slower than that of NetLogo. Is it likely the problem with my code, or can it be the inherent limitation of Python?

Obviously, this is just a fragment of the code, but that's where Python spends two-thirds of the run-time. I hope if I wrote something really inefficient it might show up in this fragment:

```
UP = (0, -1)
RIGHT = (1, 0)
DOWN = (0, 1)
LEFT = (-1, 0)
all_directions = [UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT]
# point is just a tuple (x, y)
def look_around(self):
    max_sugar_point = self.point
    max_sugar = self.world.sugar_map[self.point].level
    min_range = 0

    random.shuffle(self.all_directions)
    for r in range(1, self.vision+1):
        for d in self.all_directions:
            p = ((self.point[0] + r * d[0]) % self.world.surface.length,
                (self.point[1] + r * d[1]) % self.world.surface.height)
            if self.world.occupied(p): # checks if p is in a lookup table (dict)
                continue
            if self.world.sugar_map[p].level > max_sugar:
                max_sugar = self.world.sugar_map[p].level
                max_sugar_point = p
    if max_sugar_point is not self.point:
        self.move(max_sugar_point)
```

Roughly equivalent [code in NetLogo](http://backspaces.net/models/sugarscape.html) (this fragment does a bit more than the Python function above):

```
; -- The SugarScape growth and motion procedures. --
to M    ; Motion rule (page 25)
    locals [ps p v d]
    set ps (patches at-points neighborhood) with [count turtles-here = 0]
    if (count ps > 0) [
        set v psugar-of max-one-of ps [psugar]              ; v is max sugar w/in vision
        set ps ps with [psugar = v]                         ; ps is legal sites w/ v sugar
        set d distance min-one-of ps [distance myself]      ; d is min dist from me to ps agents
        set p random-one-of ps with [distance myself = d]   ; p is one of the min dist patches
        if (psugar >= v and includeMyPatch?) [set p patch-here]
        setxy pxcor-of p pycor-of p                         ; jump to p
        set sugar sugar + psugar-of p                       ; consume its sugar
        ask p [setpsugar 0]                                 ; .. setting its sugar to 0
    ]
    set sugar sugar - metabolism    ; eat sugar (metabolism)
    set age age + 1
end
```

On my computer, the Python code takes 15.5 sec to run 1000 steps; on the same laptop, the NetLogo simulation running in Java inside the browser finishes 1000 steps in less than 6 sec.

EDIT: Just checked Repast, using Java implementation. And it's also about the same as NetLogo at 5.4 sec. [Recent comparisons](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/compare.php?lang=python3&lang2=java) between Java and Python suggest no advantage to Java, so I guess it's just my code that's to blame?

EDIT: I understand [MASON](http://web.mac.com/tony.bigbee/mason_sugarscape/MASON_Sugarscape.html) is supposed to be even faster than Repast, and yet it still runs Java in the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This probably won't give dramatic speedups, but you should be aware that local variables are quite a bit faster in Python compared to accessing globals or attributes. So you could try assigning some values that are used in the inner loop into locals, like this:

```
def look_around(self):
    max_sugar_point = self.point
    max_sugar = self.world.sugar_map[self.point].level
    min_range = 0

    selfx = self.point[0]
    selfy = self.point[1]
    wlength = self.world.surface.length
    wheight = self.world.surface.height
    occupied = self.world.occupied
    sugar_map = self.world.sugar_map
    all_directions = self.all_directions

    random.shuffle(all_directions)
    for r in range(1, self.vision+1):
        for dx,dy in all_directions:
            p = ((selfx + r * dx) % wlength,
                (selfy + r * dy) % wheight)
            if occupied(p): # checks if p is in a lookup table (dict)
                continue
            if sugar_map[p].level > max_sugar:
                max_sugar = sugar_map[p].level
                max_sugar_point = p
    if max_sugar_point is not self.point:
        self.move(max_sugar_point)
```

Function calls in Python also have a relatively high overhead (compared to Java), so you can try to further optimize by replacing the `occupied` function with a direct dictionary lookup.

You should also take a look at [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/). It's a just-in-time compiler for Python that can give dramatic speed improvements in some cases. However, it doesn't support Python 3.x yet, so you would need to use an older version of Python.

Comment: Nice. Execution time fell from 15.5 to 11.4 sec (~26%). Why the hell wouldn't Python optimize that stuff, at least when I specify -O option to the interpreter???

Comment: And fell further to 10.4 sec when I got rid of `occupied` function.

Comment: @ max: Thanks for writing back with speed-ups that you experienced.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that the way that `neighborhood` is implemented in NetLogo is different from the double loop you have. Specifically, I think they pre-calculate a neighborhood vector like

```
n = [ [0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0]....]
```

(you would need a different one for vision=1,2,...) and then use just one loop over `n` instead of a nested loop like you are doing. This eliminates the need for the multiplications.

I don't think this will get you 3X speedup.

Comment: We need a random point among the highest sugar points. In my approach, it's done by a single `shuffle` on directions before the loop. In NetLogo, it's done by keeping track of all the best points and then choosing one at random from the list (I tried that in Python but it was slightly slower). In your approach, I would either need to try keeping track of multiple best points again, or to `shuffle` each of the neighborhood vectors (n `shuffle`s instead of one). I'll try.

Comment: And also, since I need to check wrapping around in the torus, I'd need to either precalculate the neighborhood for each point or else to keep using `%` operation. The former is a few percent faster, the latter is much slower.

Comment: A faster way to get the wrap-around world behavior from netLogo would be to make your world modeled within a numpy array with extra indices at both ends in the x- and y-directions. If the neighbor distance were 1, the array indices would run from 0 to width+1 and from 0 to height+1. Calculations need only be done within the subset of indices representing the world, and then patch values for the extra indices at either end of each dimension can be copied from the world at the other end. This avoids the % calculation for each python equivalent of the netLogo patch in the world's interior.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I suggest you look into using NumPy for speeding up your operations. Places where you use dicts and lists which are logically organized (1-, 2-, 3-, or N-dimensional grid) homogenous data object (all integers, or all floats, etc) will have less overhead when represented and accessed as Numpy arrays.

http://numpy.org

Answer (score 3):

Here is a relatively up to date comparison of NetLogo and one version of Repast. I would not necessarily assumed Repast is faster. NetLogo seems to contain some very smart algorithms that can make up for whatever costs it has.
http://condor.depaul.edu/slytinen/abm/Lytinen-Railsback-EMCSR_2012-02-17.pdf